# remove extra white space and invisible chars from string using java

Tags: java, string, apache-stringutils

I have a big conversation, I am handling it as String in between the string there are many white spaces may be invisible non word characters also. 
Below is an example string:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String str = " TWD day count Spot                              6-Sep / 2-Sep 2016 1W7d                        13-Sep / 9-Sep 2016 1M30d                      6-Oct / 4-Oct 2016 2M62d                      7-Nov / 3-Nov 2016 3M91d                      6-Dec / 2-Dec 2016 6M181d                    6-Mar / 2-Mar 2017 9M273d                    6-Jun / 2-Jun 2017 12M365d                  6-Sep / 4-Sep 2017 18M546d                  6-Mar / 2-Mar 2018 24M730d                  6-Sep / 4-Sep 2018";
  str = str.toString().replaceAll(" +", "");
  System.out.println("str="+str.toString().trim().replaceAll(" ", ""));
}
```

I tried many string functions to remove white spaces like `trim()`, `replaceAll(" ","")`, `replaceAll("\\s","")`, `replaceAll(" +","")`, `replaceAll("\\s\\u00a0","")`, `stringUtils.normalize()` function etc. Many I tried but not working as expected.

I am expecting the output as below:

> "String str = " TWD day count Spot 6-Sep / 2-Sep 2016 1W7d 13-Sep /
>   9-Sep 2016 1M30d 6-Oct / 4-Oct 2016 2M62d 7-Nov / 3-Nov 2016
>   3M91d 6-Dec / 2-Dec 2016 6M181d 6-Mar / 2-Mar 2017 9M273d "

Just one space instead of long white duplicate spaces.

Please help.

Found the answer as below:

```
System.out.println("str="+str.replaceAll("(?U)\\s+", " "));
```

Comment: What is the point of `str.toString()` when `str` is already a `String`? --- What is the point of `.trim().replaceAll(" ", "")` when the `replaceAll` will remove the leading and trailing spaces anyway?

Comment: *not working as expected* Unless you explain the exact problem, all we can do is repeat the same suggestions.

Comment: maybe `System.out.println("str="+str.replaceAll("\\s+", " "));`

Comment: @Andreas I agree, just deleted my answer and upvoted yours.

Comment: Ooh, `.replaceAll("(?U)\\s+", " ")` helped me, thanks.

Answer (score 9):

If you have non-standard spaces in your text, such as characters from Unicode categories:

- [Separator, Space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Zs/list.htm), e.g. `\u00A0` (NO-BREAK SPACE), `\u2003` (EM SPACE), ...
- [Separator, Paragraph](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Zp/list.htm), i.e. `\u2029` (PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR)
- [Separator, Line](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Zl/list.htm), i.e. `\u2028` (LINE SEPARATOR)

use this:

```
str = str.replaceAll("[\\s\\p{Z}]+", " ").trim();
```

where `\s` matches whitespace characters (`[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]`), and `\p{Z}` is shorthand for `\p{Zs}\p{Zp}\p{Zl}` as listed above.

It will basically replace all *whitespace* and *separator* characters into spaces, collapse consecutive spaces into a single space, and remove leading and trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String []args){
    String str = " TWD day count Spot                              6-Sep / 2-Sep 2016 1W7d                        13-Sep / 9-Sep 2016 1M30d                      6-Oct / 4-Oct 2016 2M62d                      7-Nov / 3-Nov 2016 3M91d                      6-Dec / 2-Dec 2016 6M181d                    6-Mar / 2-Mar 2017 9M273d                    6-Jun / 2-Jun 2017 12M365d                  6-Sep / 4-Sep 2017 18M546d                  6-Mar / 2-Mar 2018 24M730d                  6-Sep / 4-Sep 2018";
    str = str.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Output:

```
TWD day count Spot 6-Sep / 2-Sep 2016 1W7d 13-Sep / 9-Sep 2016 1M30d 6-Oct / 4-Oct 2016 2M62d 7-Nov / 3-Nov 2016 3M91d 6-Dec / 2-Dec 2016 6M181d 6-Mar / 2-Mar 2017 9M273d 6-Jun / 2-Jun 2017 12M365d 6-Sep / 4-Sep 2017 18M546d 6-Mar / 2-Mar 2018 24M730d 6-Sep / 4-Sep 2018
```

Answer (score 0):

use `StringUtils.normalizeSpace(str);`

Output:

```
TWD day count Spot 6-Sep / 2-Sep 2016 1W7d 13-Sep / 9-Sep 2016 1M30d 6-Oct / 4-Oct 2016 2M62d 7-Nov / 3-Nov 2016 3M91d 6-Dec / 2-Dec 2016 6M181d 6-Mar / 2-Mar 2017 9M273d 6-Jun / 2-Jun 2017 12M365d 6-Sep / 4-Sep 2017 18M546d 6-Mar / 2-Mar 2018 24M730d 6-Sep / 4-Sep 2018
```